# Cómo conservar el orden de un ArrayList tras convertirlo a Map con Java Stream

Tags: java, lista, map, stream

A partir de un ArrayList, con los datos organizados, quiero crear una mapa organizado.

```
Map<Usuario, List<Cargo>> curriculums = listaUsuario.stream()
    .map(t -> (Map.Entry<Usuario, List<Cargo>>) t)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

Tras ejecutar el código, el mapa pierde el orden del ArrayList.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que se pierda el órden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es usar la versión de toMap de cuatro argumentos:

```
Map<Usuario, List<Cargo>> curriculums= listaUsuarios.stream()
        .map(t -> (Map.Entry<Usuario, List<Cargo>>) t)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue(), (u, v) -> {
          throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Clave duplicada %s", u));
      },
      LinkedHashMap::new));
```

En el último argumento se define el tipo de mapa al que se quiere convertir. LinkedHashMap mantiene el orden en que estaban los datos en el ArrayList.